# Fallacy of affirming the conclusion question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm a little unsure about the exact reason why/when you get "fallacy of affirming the conclusion"

In this simple example:

$$p\rightarrow q $$
$$q$$
$$----$$
$$\therefore p$$

Not exactly sure how I would format that but anyways,  for the argument to be valid if $p \rightarrow q$ and $q$ are both true then $p$ must also be true. Is it an invalid statement because if $p$ is false and $q$ is true then $p \rightarrow q$ is true therefore, the fact that $p$ can be either false or true instead of it needing to be true makes it invalid?

Also, could someone explain to me why

$$p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$$
$$q \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$$
$$-------$$
$$\therefore (p \vee q) \rightarrow r$$

is an invalid statement?

Comment: So then all instances must conform to the conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument $p \rightarrow q, q \vdash p$ is a fallacy because if $p$ is false and $q$ is true then both $p \rightarrow q, q $ are true but the conclusion $p$ is false.

For the second argument, if $p$ is false, $q$ is true and $r$ is false we see that
$p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$ is true and $q \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$ is true but the conclusion $(p \lor q) \rightarrow r$ is false. Hence this argument is also a fallacy.

(However, the argument $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r), q \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r) \vdash (p \land q) \rightarrow r$ is valid.)

In both cases, a truth table illustrates the issue.